# Reading URL with # instead of ? in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, web

I am workign with OAuth2 and and I am calling Google API. Google returns results after call is complete and I am supposed to read from the query parameters. Now, the kind of URL that Google Returns is weird and it has anchor # in it exactly where there should be a ?

and URL looks something like

http://localhost.contestfactory.com/enduser/#state=MDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTjWwx7hHO4WnmfQ_lwJSpATCqA_DUZCC_ZIjdyPWA96OS0EN0&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

Because of # in the URL my C# code fails to read beyond #. Is there anyway I can deal this problem in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part after the `#` is called the URL fragment (or hash).

It is never sent to the server.

Comment: So you mean there is no way that server would be able to read this and if I want to read it then i have to handle that info in client side?

Comment: @Californicated yeah the intention is for usage with internal page links and javascript

Answer (score 2):

what ur saying looks like hash fragment.. and it is never sen tto the server. what u can do instead make a JS script that changes all the `"#" to "?"` that way they will be treated as query string and will be sent to the server